# Replace custom callback interface by coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Android Studio 3.6

My custom callback interface:

```
interface RecoveryPasswordConfirmCodeCallback {
    fun onSuccess()
    fun onError(ex: Throwable?)
}
```

Use:

```
val result = TransportService.recoverPasswordConfirmCode(
                    confirmCode,
                    ex,
                    object : RecoveryPasswordConfirmCodeCallback {
                        override fun onSuccess() {

                        }

                        override fun onError(ex: Throwable?) {

                            if (ex is InvalidOtpException) {
                                toastMessage.value = SingleEvent(
                                    getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.getString(
                                        R.string.incorrect_confirm_code
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                toastMessage.value = SingleEvent(
                                    getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.getString(
                                        R.string.default_error_message
                                    ))
                            }
                        }
                    })


 fun recoverPasswordConfirmCode(
            confirmCode: String,
            ex: NeedTfaException,
            callBack: RecoveryPasswordConfirmCodeCallback
        ) {
           //some code here
        }
```

Nice. It's work fine. But... is it possible to replace my custom callback interface by Kotlin's coroutine. I don't want to create custom interface only for execute method `recoverPasswordConfirmCode`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `recoverPasswordConfirmCode()`  to a suspend function and return the result in the form of a sealed class to indicate if it's an error or the valid response. Something like this:

```
// Generic response class
sealed class Response<out T>{
    data class Error(val ex: Throwable) : Response<Nothing>()
    data class Data<T>(val data: T) : Response<T>()
}

// in your TransportService class
suspend fun recoverPasswordConfirmCode(confirmCode, ex): Response<RecoverPasswordResponse>{
    // Do your stuff here 
    // return Response.Data<RecoverPasswordResponse>(/* your data object here */)

}
```

Then call it like this and check the response type:

```
val result = TransportService.recoverPasswordConfirmCode(confirmCode, ex)
when(result){
    is Response.Error -> // Do something
    is Response.Data -> // Do something
}
```

Note that you will have to call the suspend function inside a coroutine context.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom interface. Consume your API like this:

```
suspend fun recoverPasswordConfirmCode(confirmCode: String): YourReturnType = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    try {
        val result = //Do your blocking API calls here
        if(result.code == confirmCode) //Check confirm code is correct
            cont.resume(YourResult) //Return your result here
        else
            cont.resumeWithException(YourException) //Throw an exception otherwise
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        cont.resumeWithException(e)
    }
}
```

Call `recoverPasswordConfirmCode` method inside a Coroutine Scope.